# R set flextable overall width 100% while two columns widths are fixed

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I have a table with three columns. First and third should have a width of 5 cm, second should autofit for an overall width of 100%.

here is my minimum .rmd

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(flextable)

data <- data.frame(
name = c("John", "Jane", "Tom"),
age = c(25, 30, 35),
height = c(176, 180, 178)
)

ft <- flextable(data)
ft <- set_table_properties(ft, width = 1, layout = "autofit")
ft <- width(ft, j = 1, width = 5, unit = "cm")
ft <- width(ft, j = 3, width = 5, unit = "cm")
ft <- theme_box(ft)
ft
```
````

I set the overall width to 100%, which works fine

```
ft <- set_table_properties(ft, width = 1, layout = "autofit")
```

and the column widths to 5 cm, which works fine without autofit

```
ft <- width(ft, j = 1, width = 5, unit = "cm")
ft <- width(ft, j = 3, width = 5, unit = "cm")
```

So the table is 100%, while column widths are ignored and set by autofit. User documentation says "If layout is autofit, column widths will not be used", so I know that it won't work this way...

Would be nice if there is some way to have only the width of the second column autofitting, leaving the widths of columns one and three at 5 cm.